# Code Review of Haskell PBKDF2

Tags: haskell, cryptography

Moved from Programmers.SE.

I have written a new version of the PBKDF2 algorithm in Haskell. It passes all of the HMAC-SHA-1 test vectors listed in [RFC 6070](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt), but it is not very efficient. How can I improve the code? I plan to upload it to Github (and maybe Hackage) once it is improved.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{- Copyright 2013, G. Ralph Kuntz, MD. All rights reserved. LGPL License. -}

module Crypto where

import Codec.Utils (Octet)
import qualified Data.Binary as B (encode)
import Data.Bits (xor)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C (pack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L (unpack)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.HMAC (hmac_sha1)
import Text.Bytedump (dumpRaw)

-- Calculate the PBKDF2 as a hexadecimal string
pbkdf2
  :: ([Octet] -> [Octet] -> [Octet])  -- pseudo random function (HMAC)
  -> Int  -- hash length in bytes
  -> String  -- password
  -> String  -- salt
  -> Int  -- iterations
  -> Int  -- derived key length in bytes
  -> String
pbkdf2 prf hashLength password salt iterations keyLength =
  let
    passwordOctets = stringToOctets password
    saltOctets = stringToOctets salt
    totalBlocks =
      ceiling $ (fromIntegral keyLength :: Double) / fromIntegral hashLength
    blockIterator message acc =
      foldl' (\(a, m) _ ->
        let !m' = prf passwordOctets m
        in (zipWith xor a m', m')) (acc, message) [1..iterations]
  in
    dumpRaw $ take keyLength $ foldl' (\acc block ->
      acc ++ fst (blockIterator (saltOctets ++ intToOctets block)
                      (replicate hashLength 0))) [] [1..totalBlocks]
  where
    intToOctets :: Int -> [Octet]
    intToOctets i =
      let a = L.unpack . B.encode $ i
      in drop (length a - 4) a

    stringToOctets :: String -> [Octet]
    stringToOctets = L.unpack . C.pack

-- Calculate the PBKDF2 as a hexadecimal string using HMAC and SHA-1
pbkdf2HmacSha1
  :: String  -- password
  -> String  -- salt
  -> Int  -- iterations
  -> Int  -- derived key length in bytes
  -> String
pbkdf2HmacSha1 =
  pbkdf2 hmac_sha1 20
```

Comment: Do you have a test suite that measures the algorithm's performance? It'd be much easier to test ideas for improvements.

Comment: I have a test suite that confirms that it passes the test vectors. My suite does not currently check performance. Still learning testing in Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [comments on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18718103/1333025) give some good hints. The most critical part is obviously `blockIterator`, so let's make it a separate function:

```
blockIterator
    :: ([Octet] -> [Octet] -> [Octet])  -- ^ pseudo random function (HMAC)
    -> [Octet]                          -- ^ password octets
    -> Int                              -- ^ iterations
    -> [Octet]                          -- ^ m
    -> [Octet]                          -- ^ a
    -> [Octet]
```

The implementation using folds on a list is nice and concise, but processing the list adds some unnecessary overhead, and prevents possible optimizations. If we instead rewrite it as a recursive function

```
blockIterator prf passwordOctets = loop
  where
    loop i m a | i == 0     = a
               | otherwise  = let m' = prf passwordOctets m
                                  a' = zipWith xor a m'
                               in a' `deepseq` 
                                  m' `deepseq`
                                  loop (i - 1) m' a'
```

it gets somewhat faster. I also added `deepseq` on the octet lists so that they're fully evaluated at each round. Introducing the recursion inside `loop`, instead of making the whole `blockIterator` recursive allows GHC to inline it.

Measuring performance can be done using the *criterion* package:

```
import Criterion.Main

-- ...

main = do
    let stdtest n = pbkdf2HmacSha1 "password" "salt" n 20
    defaultMain [ bgroup "stdtest" $
                    map (\n -> bench (show n) (nf stdtest n))
                        [1, 2, 4096, 65536 ]
                ]
```

However, the far most time-consuming part is still processing lists inside `blockIterator`. Using [unboxed ST arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STUArray) would make the code way faster. There would be no memory allocation in the loop, no need to force evaluation. The problem is, `hmac_sha1` is implemented using list, so we'd need another optimized, `ST`-based implementation.